# Angular adal Can't access api

Tags: angular, azure, azure-active-directory

I have implemented a angular app for that Azure directory is used for authentication. After login i'm getting a access token using that i can't access the api. It's giving me an error that 'Authorization has been denied for this request'.

i have added all configuration like this

```
tenant: *******,
clientId: *********,
redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200',
extraQueryParameter: 'nux=1',
postLogoutRedirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200'
```

Answer (score 0):

If your Web API is defined as a separate entry (client ID) in Azure AD, you need to explicitly request an `access_token` for that resource.

Something like this for vanilla JS - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi/blob/master/TodoSPA/App/Scripts/Ctrls/todoListCtrl.js#L16

See the [source code here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi/blob/0a2f11dad9b705f9550f64198f0abfb1954bf36e/TodoSPA/App/Scripts/adal.js#L316-L350) to better understand the mechanics of calling that function.

Since this is implicit flow, make sure your JavaScript app (its client ID) has permissions to access the Web API, edit the manifest to enable **implicit flow** and press the **Grant Permissions** button in Azure AD portal to inhibit consent prompts.

Comment: Are you acquiring the token for the exact audience value your API is expecting? You're really not giving us much to work with here.

Comment: I'm having the same tenant id for api and the front end, But different client id